# Meeting Request With Webform submissions

Tags: webforms

I'm trying to send meeting request to user after they submit a webform.

In this webform, they can fill in a start date and stop date (for exemple).

And I would like to get the value of start date in the webform to use it in my meeting request.

I can send this meeting request with the code below:

```
function sendIcalEvent($from_name, $from_address, $to_name, $to_address,     $startTime, $endTime, $subject, $description, $location)
{
$domain = 'domain.tld';

//Create Email Headers
$mime_boundary = "----Meeting Booking----".MD5(TIME());

$headers = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$mime_boundary\"\n";
$headers .= "Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage\n";

//Create Email Body (HTML)
$message = "--$mime_boundary\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
$message .= "<html>\n";
$message .= "<body>\n";
$message .= '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
$message .= "</body>\n";
$message .= "</html>\n";
$message .= "--$mime_boundary\r\n";

$ical = 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR' . "\r\n" .
'PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 10.0 MIMEDIR//EN' . "\r\n" .
'VERSION:2.0' . "\r\n" .
'METHOD:REQUEST' . "\r\n" .
'BEGIN:VTIMEZONE' . "\r\n" .
'TZID:Romance Standard Time' . "\r\n" .
'BEGIN:STANDARD' . "\r\n" .
'DTSTART:16011028T030000' . "\r\n" .
'RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11' . "\r\n" .
'TZOFFSETFROM:+0200' . "\r\n" .
'TZOFFSETTO:+0100' . "\r\n" .
'TZNAME:Romance Standard Time' . "\r\n" .
'END:STANDARD' . "\r\n" .
'BEGIN:DAYLIGHT' . "\r\n" .
'DTSTART:16010325T020000' . "\r\n" .
'RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3' . "\r\n" .
'TZOFFSETFROM:+0200' . "\r\n" .
'TZOFFSETTO:+0100' . "\r\n" .
'TZNAME:EDST' . "\r\n" .
'END:DAYLIGHT' . "\r\n" .
'END:VTIMEZONE' . "\r\n" .  
'BEGIN:VEVENT' . "\r\n" .
'ORGANIZER;CN="'.$from_name.'":MAILTO:'.$from_address. "\r\n" .
'ATTENDEE;CN="'.$to_name.'";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:'.$to_address. "\r\n" .
'LAST-MODIFIED:' . date("Ymd\TGis") . "\r\n" .
'UID:'.date("Ymd\TGis", strtotime($startTime)).rand()."@".$domain."\r\n" .
'DTSTAMP:'.date("Ymd\TGis"). "\r\n" .
'DTSTART;TZID="Romance Standard Time":'.date("Ymd\THis", strtotime($startTime)). "\r\n" .
'DTEND;TZID="Romance Standard Time":'.date("Ymd\THis", strtotime($endTime)). "\r\n" .
'TRANSP:OPAQUE'. "\r\n" .
'SEQUENCE:1'. "\r\n" .
'SUMMARY:' . $subject . "\r\n" .
'LOCATION:' . $location . "\r\n" .
'CLASS:PUBLIC'. "\r\n" .
'PRIORITY:5'. "\r\n" .
'BEGIN:VALARM' . "\r\n" .
'TRIGGER:-PT15M' . "\r\n" .
'ACTION:DISPLAY' . "\r\n" .
'DESCRIPTION:Reminder' . "\r\n" .
'END:VALARM' . "\r\n" .
'END:VEVENT'. "\r\n" .
'END:VCALENDAR'. "\r\n";
$message .= 'Content-Type: text/calendar;name="meeting.ics";method=REQUEST'."\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
$message .= $ical;

$mailsent = mail($to_address, $subject, $message, $headers);

return ($mailsent)?(true):(false);
}
$from_name = "webmaster";        
$from_address = "webmaster@domain.tld";        
$to_name = "Name";        
$to_address = "user@domain.tld";        
$startTime = $date;        
$endTime = "07/01/2015 02:00";        
$subject = "Test Subject";        
$description = "description";       
$location = "FlowLine";
sendIcalEvent($from_name, $from_address, $to_name, $to_address,$startTime,$endTime, $subject, $description, $location);
```

So I use this code in my confirmation page.

BUT I would like that startime = [submission:values:date]... (date is a webform field name)

How can I make it possible? Maybe using the confirmation page is not the wright way...

I am not a developer, I would like to modify the webform code the less I can.

EDIT: I achieve this, like this:

- In the webform, I configure a Custom URL redirecting to a Basic Page.
- The Basic Page contain the PHP code to generate the appointment.
- In the custom URL, I use all the [submission:values:] I need.
- In the PHP script, I get the submission I need with some $_GET[var];

Comment: As a workaround, I tried to use "exec" command to execute a php script with some submission value as argument:


$date = '[submission:values:date]';

exec('php send_meeting_request.php $date');

But $date is not interpreted... is there a way to make it possible?

Comment: you probably want to override the validation handler for the form and include the call to your function there, once validation is complete and everything is good

Comment: Probably, but I have no idea how to do That ^^

Comment: RE "I would like to modify the webform code the less I can." You should not modify a module at all. If you need extra functionality, you need to create a module.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! You seem to be using not Drupal code for a Drupal site. Answering the question would require us to explain you how to write a module, and this is something we assume you know.

Comment: "How to create a module" is also a too broad topic for us to answer. There is plenty of documentation on drupal.org, and we would just duplicate that documentation. If you had a specific question about that, we could answer it.

Answer (score 1):

I have never worked with WebForms before, I normally build forms from scratch, but it does have a number of hooks available, you can see them [here:](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!webform.api.php/group/webform_hooks/7)

The general idea, would be to use something like `hook_webform_component_presave()`-

- Create a new custom module (this can be at theme as well, but module spans all themes); custom_ical_event is the module's short name I use in this exammple

  custom_ical_events.info

  ```
  name = Custom iCal Event
  core = 7.x
  description = Automatically sends an iCal Event after a webform submission
  ```

  custom_ical_events.module

  ```
  function custom_ical_event_webform_component_presave(&$component) {
    dpm($component);  // retrieve devel information for component array

    if (//form is the form you want) {
      // set data elements, $component contains the form submission data
      // input custom code, or better yet, a call to a function that incorporates
      // the custom code
    }
  }
  ```
- You will need to do some sleuthing to get the correct information. I included a call to `dpm()` from the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module.

> A suite of modules containing fun for module developers and themers

Basically, you will need to check an element inside the component variable array to make sure you are looking at the correct form, and then access the data, which will depend on your set up of the webform itself, so I can't be more specific. `dpm()` will show the array structure, you just need to use the correct element (i.e. `if ($component->type == 'my_webform_type') ...`).

- Once everything looks good, remove the `dpm($component);` line.

Comment: Since the OP wants to access the value of a webform element, this answer is more helpful to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine you will need to use [hook_mail_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7) to alter the properties of the outgoing e-mail, but I don't expect it to be easy or straightforward.

You may want to take a look at the [Mime Mail](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail) module to try and understand how that module alters outgoing messages to allow HTML messages as by default Drupal only sends messages as plain text.

Comment: The OP is asking how to get the value of a webform element. They need a  Webform hook, and call the Drupal function that sends email in that hook. The alter hook should be used to alter the email sent from another module.

Comment: Which would be available inside hook_mail_alter as all outgoing emails go through this hook, whether it's a Webform or a regular Drupal form.

Comment: hook_mail_alter() doesn't have access to node or form data.

Comment: It does, but not directly. The params key is an array of optional parameters supplied by the caller of drupal_mail() that is used to build the message before hook_mail_alter() is invoked. Therefore it's possible to access the nid and sid relating to the node and webform submission